# How to find a substring in a line and append from that line up to the next substring?

Tags: python, file, substring, line

The test.txt would be

```
1
2
3
start
4
5
6
end
7
8
9
```

I would like the result to be

```
start
4
5
6
end
```

This is my code

```
file = open('test.txt','r')

line = file.readline()

start_keyword = 'start'
end_keyword = 'end'

lines = []

while line: 
    line = file.readlines() 
    for words_in_line in line: 
        if start_keyword in words_in_line:
            lines.append(words_in_line)

file.close()

print entities
```

It returns

```
['start\n']
```

I have no idea what to add to the above code to achieve the result I want to get. I have been searching and changing the code around but I don't know how to get this to work as I want it to.

Comment: .strip('\n') to get rid of newline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a flag. Try this:

```
file = open('test.txt','r')

start_keyword = 'start'
end_keyword = 'end'
in_range = False
entities = []

lines = file.readlines()

for line in lines:

    line = line.strip()

    if line == start_keyword:
        in_range = True
    elif line == end_keyword:
        in_range = False

    elif in_range:
        entities.append(line)

file.close()

# If you want to include the start/end tags
#entities = [start_keyword] + entities + [end_keyword]

print entities
```

About your code, notice that [readlines](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readlines.htm) already reads all lines in a file, so calling [readline](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readline.htm) doesn't seem to make much sense, unless you are ignoring the first line. Also use [strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) to remove EOL characters from the strings. Notice how your code doesn't do what you expect it to:

```
# Reads ALL lines in the file as an array
line = file.readlines() 

# You are not iterating words in a line, but rather all lines one by one
for words_in_line in line:

    # If a given line contains 'start', append it. This is why you only get ['start\n'], it's the only line you are adding as no other line contains that string
    if start_keyword in words_in_line:
        lines.append(words_in_line)
```

Comment: Wow... this is perfect... you are a genius

Comment: I'm glad it helped! Maybe you should accept the answer if it solved your problem. Best.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some kind of a flag that gets set to true when you encounter the `start_keyword` and if that flag is set you add the lines to `lines` list, and it gets unset when `end_keyword` is encountered (but only after end_keyword has been written into the `lines` list.

Also use `.strip()` on `words_in_line` to remove the `\n` (and other trailing and leading whitespaces) If you do not want them in the list `lines` , if you do want them, then don't strip it.

Example -

```
flag = False
for words_in_line in line: 
    if start_keyword in words_in_line:
        flag = True
    if flag:
        lines.append(words_in_line.strip())
    if end_keyword in words_in_line:
        flag = False
```

Please note, this would add multiple `start` to `end` blocks into the `lines` list, I am guessing that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need a state variable to decide whether you are storing the lines or not.  Here is a simplistic example that will always store the line, and then will change its mind and discard it for the cases you don't want:

```
start_keyword = 'start'
end_keyword = 'end'

lines = []
reading = False
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        lines.append(line)
        if start_keyword in line:
            reading = True
        elif end_keyword in line:
            reading = False
        elif not reading:
            lines.pop()

print ''.join(lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the file isn't too big (relative to how much RAM your computer has):

```
start = 'start'
end = 'end'

with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    result = content[content.index(start):content.index(end)]
```

You can then print it with `print(result)`, create a `list` by using `result.split()`, and so on.

If there are multiple start/stop points, and/or the file is very large:

```
start = 'start'
end = 'end'
running = False
result = []

with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if start in line:
            running = True
            result.append(line)
        elif end in line:
            running = False
            result.append(line)
        elif running:
            result.append(line)
```

This leaves you with a `list`, which you can `join()`, `print()`, write to a file, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

A file object is it's own iterator, you don't need a while loop to read a file line by line, you can iterate over the file object itself. To catch the sections just start an inner loopn when you encounter a line with `start` and break the inner loop when you hit `end`:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    out = []
    for line in f:
        if start in line:
            out.append(line)
            for _line in f:
                out.append(_line)
                if end in  _line:
                    break
```

Output:

```
['start\n', '4\n', '5\n', '6\n', 'end\n']
```